# How to create a compile-time static class type that initializes a member container with specific values?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

This is basically what I want:

```
struct Item{
   int id;
   std::string s;   
};

template <???>
struct StaticContainer
{
    static const std::deque<Item> _items;
};

template <???>
const std::deque<Item> StaticContainer<>::_items {???};
```

Doesn't have to be a `deque`, I just want to associate an iterable list of values with a `type`. So that I can do stuff like

```
typedef StaticContainer<{{1, "a", {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}}> T1;
typedef StaticContainer<{{0, "e"}, {-1, "f"}, {-2, "g"}}> T2;

int main() {
   T1 t1;
   T2 t2;
   t1 = t2; // Error: incompatible types

   return 0;
}
```

Usually it's making things dynamic that's the problem, but apparently it's just as hard to to make some dynamic things to be compile-time.
I do not want to use inheritance, polymorphism and similar runtime, overhead-inducing approaches.

Comment: just use non-type template parameters: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47747401cd58d84c

Comment: @m.s.: but how do I initialize `_items` then? I need to put the list values this type was created with there.

Comment: If you want a compile-time list of values, why do you need to store them in a *container* at all?

Comment: depends on your needs, you could use a tuple ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3d5b64865b1512b)) or a std::array( [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c09c2eecd894fdd))

Comment: @NicolBolas: in order to iterate over the list.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe when do you want to iterate? at compile time or at runtime? If you explain in more detail what your actual use case is, someone might provide you with a fitting solution

Comment: @m.s.: at runtime. The tuple is not [easily] iterable, so I'll pass on that. An array would be great, but I want a custom type for an item, not `int` (edited the question some time after posting). Doesn't look like your `array` solution will work with my `Item` type.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: "*in order to iterate over the list.*" The compile-time side of C++ is a pathway to many abilities *some* consider to be... unnatural. You can use metaprogramming techniques to iterate over the values in a list without a container.

Comment: @NicolBolas: right. Fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have a compile-time list of user-defined structs. And you cannot have a compile-time `std::string` *of any kind*. It is not a [literal type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType), and therefore cannot be used in any `constexpr` context.

If you restrict yourself to types that can be used in [non-type template parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters), then you can use a variadic template type. And then, you don't have to bother with the runtime container:

```
template<typename T, T ...ts>
struct value_list
{
    //Not the most efficient way to get a value.
    template<int ix>
    static constexpr auto get()
    { return std::get<ix>(std::make_tuple(ts...)); }

    //Get a general container
    template<typename Container>
    static auto get_container() {return Container{ts...};}

    //Get an array, appropriately sized.
    static constexpr auto get_array()
    { return std::array<T, sizeof...(ts)>{ts...}; }

    //Manipulators. Types are static, so they must return
    //new types with the new values.
    template<T new_val>
    constexpr auto push_back()
    {return value_list<T, ts..., new_val>();}

    template<T new_val>
    constexpr auto push_front()
    {return value_list<T, new_val, ts...>();}
};
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/IuAELw).

However, be advised that compilers have fairly strict limits on the number of template parameters a type can have. You probably won't blow past this limit by typing them in on a keyboard, but you can construct them past it.

Comment: And if my `Item` is not just an `int` but a `struct` of `int` and `std::string`, I'm entirely out of luck?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Was there some ambiguity in my very first sentence? If you want to have lists of *values* which are defined *and used* at compile-time, then they must be things which can go into non-type template argument lists. And `std::string` isn't even a literal type: you *cannot possibly* have a value of this type at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

What about using variadic template non type arguments?

Something like

**--- edit: corrected (thanks m.s.) ---**

**--- edit2: added array _items2---**

```
#include <deque>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

struct Item{
   int id;   
};

template <int ... vals>
struct StaticContainer
{
    static const std::deque<Item> _items;
    static const std::array<Item, sizeof...(vals)> _items2;
};

template <int ... vals>
const std::deque<Item> StaticContainer<vals...>::_items { {vals}... };

template <int ... vals>
const std::array<Item, sizeof...(vals)> StaticContainer<vals...>::_items2 { { {vals} ... } };

typedef StaticContainer<1, 2, 3> T1;
typedef StaticContainer<0, -1, -2> T2;

int main ()
 {
   T1 t1;
   T2 t2;
   //t1 = t2; // Error: incompatible types

   std::cout << T1::_items[1].id << std::endl;
   std::cout << T2::_items2[0].id << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The OP explicitly asked about using a user-defined struct (`Item`) as the container's type, not `int`.

Comment: @m.s. - you're right; corrected; thanks; but you should cout `T1::_items[1].id`

Comment: Interesting idea. I can't pass `Item` as a template parameter (which would be ideal), but as far as I make it a requirement for `Item` to be constructable from `int`...

Comment: @VioletGiraffe - exactly; the limit of this solution is that the `Item`s are to be initialized with values that can fit a non type variadic template pack

Comment: @VioletGiraffe - added an `_items2` member to show how work with `std::array`

Comment: Just remembered I need `Item` to store and `int` and a `string`, and, of course, I need to specify both when constructing the list. Doesn't look like your solution is still applicable. Any advice?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe - No, sorry: I surrend. I don't know how to make it.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe - not at all: I'm trying to learn C++11 and it's a nice exercise